How do I reference a typevars' generics in type hinting?
Say I have some code like this:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic

from typing_extensions import TypeVar

A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')

DataVar = TypeVar('DataVar', bound = 'Data')

@dataclass
class Data(Generic[A, B]):
    a: A
    b: B

class Object(Generic[DataVar]):
    def __init__(self, data: DataVar) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.data: DataVar = data

    def a(self):  # -> DataVar.A
        return self.data.a
    def b(self):  # -> DataVar.B
        return self.data.b

How would I go about indicating that Object.a and Object.b do have defined return types, as specified by the data type in DataVar? I could have defined Object like:
class Object(Generic[A, B]):
    def __init__(self, data: Data[A, B]) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.data: Data[A, B] = data

    def a(self) -> A:
        return self.data.a

    def b(self) -> B:
        return self.data.b

Which could work in this instance, but what if I care about the A and B types, but also the specific subclass of Data? I can go for something like:
class Object(Generic[A, B, DataVar]):
    def __init__(self, data: DataVar) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.data: DataVar = data

    def a(self) -> A:
        return self.data.a  # type unknown

    def b(self) -> B:
        return self.data.b  # type unknown

But then the type checker can't tell that DataVar is a subclass of Data[A, B]. From my research this could be solved with something called 'higher kinded types' or HKT, but that doesn't seem to exist right now in python, is there any other way to go about this? Basically it comes down to maintaining the proper relationships between two families of objects with similar generics, but I'm running into type issues in my actual code that this is abstracted from, even though this particular code's type issues could be ignored safely.
I have done some research on the various issues, but my concepts for how type hinting might work to solve my problem are hard to put into words, and I have not come across any realizable solution, besides just don't code like this.

Can Data be subclassed? If yes, then you will need either HKTs or cast()/type: ignore. If not, make Object generic over A and B instead. Does that work for you?

It is what I was afraid of. Data, in this analogy, would be subclassed. I will simply have to make do.
